# Engineer or Architect?

Tags: attic, planning, spray-foam, attic-conversion

I have a semi-finished attic in my 1930's era cape. A shed roof was added at some point, so there is some open space and light. The square footage is counted as part of the house (well it was when I bought it).

I'm thinking about remodeling, but have some concerns, floor joist spacing (its not 16", bigger), ceiling height, "can I add a bathroom"?

Can an architect answer these questions, or would it require an engineer? Would either make the permitting process easier?

Any thoughts on closed cell spray foam directly under the roof? to make the space better insulated?

Answer (score 3):

There are many kinds of engineers and most are specialists like: civil (water, sewer, drainage, etc.); structural; mechanical (plumbing? HVAC, etc.); electrical; acoustical; etc.

Architects know building components like: windows, stairs, doors, roofing, etc. plus they know code issues like required setbacks, energy use (insulation, vapor barriers, etc.). They also know customary construction practices so you don’t get unusual joist spacing, etc. If they need electrical, plumbing, etc. help, let them hire the specialized engineer.

I’d go with an architect with residential experience. (Some Architects do schools, clinics, etc.) Ask for their resume and a list of references.

Btw, a residential architect will know a couple good contractors capable of doing the job on time and on budget. (Always get 3 bids for the work.)